# How do I render card items from array in NativeBase?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

My code is not working. I would like to render cards from the array of objects. However, it seems quite hard with NativeBase.

CardsScreen.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Text, Button, Icon, Left, Body, Right } from 'native-base';

class CardsScreen extends Component {
  props:Props;


  DATA = [
 { id: 1, title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, everti rationibus his cu', views:'200', comments:'9', published:'4h ago' image: require('../img/img1.jpeg') },

 { id: 2, title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, everti rationibus his ', Views:'700', comments:'16', published:'9h ago' image: require ('../img/img2.jpg') },

 { id: 3, title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, everti rationibus hi', Views:'698', comments:'8', published:'14h ago' image:require ('../img/img3.jpeg') },

 ];

  render() {

    let renderpostTypes = () => {

      let post = [];


      this.DATA.map( ( item )=> {

        post.push(

          <Content  key={item.id}>

             <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <Thumbnail source={require(item.image)} />
                <Body>
                  <Text>item.title</Text>
                  <Text note>GeekyAnts</Text>
                </Body>
              </Left>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem cardBody>
              <Image source={require(item.image)} style={{height: 200, width: null, flex: 1}}/>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon active name="thumbs-up" />
                  <Text>item.views</Text>
                </Button>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon active name="chatbubbles" />
                  <Text>item.comments</Text>
                </Button>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                <Text>item.published</Text>
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
          </Content>
        );
      } );

      return post;
    };

    return (
      <Container>

        <Content >
          {renderpostTypes()}
        </Content>
      </Container>);
  }
}
export default CardsScreen;
```

How can I make it work and render the cards from that array of objects? Is there any example which solves this problem?

Comment: any errors in the console ?

Comment: at the moment syntax error inside array only which I can't find out but I don't think that this code is correct.

Comment: i have try your code, but it works well iin my device :)

Answer (score 2):

i have try your code, and that works in my device. but i have one example code if you want render card using array in native base, this is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Text, Button, Icon, Left, Body, Right } from 'native-base';

class CardsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        DATA : [
          { id: 1, title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, everti rationibus his cu', views:'200', comments:'9', published:'4h ago', image: '../img/img1.jpeg' },

          { id: 2, title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, everti rationibus his ', Views:'700', comments:'16', published:'9h ago', image: '../img/img1.jpeg' },

          { id: 3, title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, everti rationibus hi', Views:'698', comments:'8', published:'14h ago', image: '../img/img1.jpeg' },
        ],
      }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
        {this.state.DATA.map((item, index) => {
          return(
            <Card key={index} >
              <CardItem>
                <Left>
                  <Thumbnail  source={require(item.image)}/>
                  <Body>
                    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                    <Text note>GeekyAnts</Text>
                  </Body>
                </Left>
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem cardBody>
                 <Image source={require(item.image)} style={{height: 200, width: null, flex: 1}} />
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem>
                <Left>
                  <Button transparent>
                    <Icon active name="thumbs-up" />
                    <Text>{item.views}</Text>
                  </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                  <Button transparent>
                    <Icon active name="chatbubbles" />
                    <Text>{item.comments}</Text>
                  </Button>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                  <Text>{item.published}</Text>
                </Right>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          );
        })}
        </Content>
      </Container>);
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ExampleApps', () => CardsScreen);
```

Hope can help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the code. It shows syntax error inside the first line { objects} of  array.

Comment: It shows error requires module '11' and instantly destroys the app inside simulator.

Comment: It cause the key from object has different, can you change `Views` key to `views` ?

Comment: Instead of AppRegistry.registerComponent('ExampleApps', () => CardsScreen);

I am using export default CardsScren;   also after changing views it shows the same requires module '11' and destroyes the app instantly.

Comment: can i see your `import` ?

Comment: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';        I've added this one into the above solution after installing prop-types package  while it destroys the app again. The only thing that I see is the message about that prop-types are separate library and you need to install and import manually while its installed. react version is 16 that is why its needed but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(yourDataArray),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <card></card>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Use list View of react native with card layout within it.The below link will be helpful.
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/listview.html#listview

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can correct your code.
Below every this been used from NATIVE BASE

```
 export default class DynamicListExample extends Component { 
     render() { 
      var items = ['Simon Mignolet','Nathaniel Clyne','Dejan']; 
     return ( 
       <Container>
        <Content>
          <List dataArray={items}
            renderRow={(item) =>
              <ListItem>
                **YOU CAN PUT YOUR HOLE CARD COMPONENT IN BETWEEN THESE LIST**
              </ListItem>
            }>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Pang for the suggestion, as I am new to stackover flow, just trying to improve things

Comment: It shows error requires module '11' and instantly destroys the app inside simulator

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example such as your code sample that used native base and handle this issue.

```
const result = this.props.articles.map((item, index) => (
    <Card key={index}>
      <CardItem header bordered>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </CardItem>
      <CardItem bordered>
        <Body>
          <Text>{item.body}</Text>
        </Body>
      </CardItem>
      <CardItem footer bordered>
        <Text>GeekyAnts</Text>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>
  ));

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>{result}</Content>
    </Container>
  );
```